# RLMArray property declaration syntax

Tags: objective-c, realm

When declaring an RLMArray, what is the significance of the second set of brackets?  Realm is the only place I've seen this used.

```
@property NSArray<NSDictionary*> *dictionaries;  // I understand this (and it's wonderful!)
@property NSDictionary<NSString*, NSArray<NSString*>*> *dictionaryOfArraysOfStrings; // No problem with this either
@property RLMArray<Object*><Object> *objects; // What is <Object> for?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two sets of angle brackets are for Objective-C generics and protocols respectively. Objective-C generics lets the compiler know that methods like `-[RLMArray firstObject]` return the specific type of object that the array contains, rather than any possible `RLMObject` subclass. Sadly this extra type information is erased at runtime, so Realm has no way to tell from the use of Objective-C generics alone in the property declaration what type of object the array contains. This is where the protocol conformance comes in. The protocol that a property conforms to *is* available to Realm at runtime, and so is used to inform Realm of the object type that your `RLMArray` property will contain. Realm [provides the `RLM_ARRAY_TYPE` macro](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/403a19ef55da6339b981e393af8ff7d47101d8ed/Realm/RLMObject.h#L432-L443) to declare a protocol of the same name as a model class, so it is easy to miss that a protocol is involved.

Comment: bdash, thank you.  I had wondered about protocols being declared with the same names as classes as well. I searched for `conformsToProtocol` in the realm source but it wasn't clear to me how this protocol is getting used. Theoretically, if I did: `@property (nonatomic) NSArray<UIViewController<UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate>*> *array; @property (nonatomic) NSArray<UIViewController*><UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate> *array2;` I again get what array is doing.  What could I do differently with array2?  Could you give me a 1-2 line example?

Comment: The use of protocols in manner I described is specific to properties of type `RLMArray` on subclasses of `RLMObject`. The two cases you mention require protocol conformance of different things: for `array`, the `UIViewController`s contained in the array must conform to the protocol. For `array2`, the array itself must conform to the protocol. The latter is unlikely to be what you're after.

Comment: bdash, I finally get it!  The brackets side by side threw me off, but it's obvious now that this is literally just a generic and a protocol at the same time. Just keep beating me on the head and I'll get there...  Thanks!